# WPF Conditional Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, conditional-statements

I have a `TreeView` and a couple of other controls like `TextBox`es and `ComboBox`es.
The `TextBox`es are bound to the selected item in the `TreeView`like this:

```
Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=groupTreeView}"
```

This works fine if all the elements in my `TreeView` have a `Name` Property.

I was wondering if there was a way to do some kind of conditional bind that would say:

```
if SelectedItem is MyTreeType
    then bind
else
    disable the element
```

Is it possible to do something like this?
Right now I'm just getting binding errors thrown and that seems a little dirty. My `TreeView` is databound and has a couple different type of classes in it so that's why I'm looking for some kind of conditional binding.

Thanks,
Raul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up creating a "CastingConverter" that I send the type in as a parameter

```
public class CastingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (parameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter");

        var type = parameter as Type;

        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("parameter must be a type");

        var itemType = value.GetType();

        if (type.IsAssignableFrom(itemType))
            return value;

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then I just bound with the following

```
DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=groupTreeView, Converter={StaticResource CastingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type vm:GroupViewModel}}"
```

Answer (score 5):

take a look at [FallbackValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx) or [TargetNullvalue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is why it's always a good idea to override `ToString` in your view classes.  Do this, and you can just bind `Text` to `SelectedItem`.

Comment: Sure that works for displaying text, but it won't support updating the Name property, and it also doesn't work if you have a lot of properties on your object.

Answer (score 1):

Look at using the [Model-View ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) (MVVM) design pattern, then your binding code is simple and the logic is in a testable class.  It is more work to start with but tends to lead to fewer problems in the long term.

Here is a very good video you should take a look at: [Jason Dolinger on Model-View-ViewModel](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650)